# Why Python does not generate all possible combinations of letters given?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, code-generation, python-itertools

## Generate the file's using code

code will return two file with possible combinations!

final file is that to use!

using itertools generating possible combinations of letters

joining tuple to string

maping output to string

writing the output to a file

Reading the generated file and removing uncessary spaces

finally Testing

## File : test.py

```
    #using itertools generating possible combinations of letters given below and writing it to a file

    from itertools import combinations

    a = "lida"
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]

    def Combinations(iterable, size):
        result = combinations(iterable, size)
        #joining tuple to string
        def join_tuple_string(strings_tuple) -> str:
            return ' '.join(strings_tuple)
        #maping output to string
        output = map(join_tuple_string, result)

        end = list(output)
        #writing the output to a file 
        with open('file.txt', 'w') as e:
            e.write(str(end))

    Combinations(letters, 4)
```

```
    #Reading the generated file and removing uncessary spaces

    with open('file.txt', 'r') as e:
        a = e.read()

        for i in range(len(a)):
            list = a[i]
            b = list.replace(' ', '')
            with open('final.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(b)
```

```
# finally Testing
with open('final.txt', 'r') as r:
    file = r.read()

    if 'adil' in file:
        print('present')

    if 'lida' in file:
        print('present')

    else:
        print('not present')
```

Comment: I don't want to click on these links. Please include relevant information directly in the question.

Comment: Please include all components of a [MCVE] as text in the body of the question, not external links. As is, without the links, you don't even have much of a question (what is the output from your tests?).

Comment: Please follow [ask] and don't put external links in your question. Instead, include a [mre]. Also, your code originally wasn't formatted correctly, because you used quotes (`'''`) and not backticks (`\`\`\``)

Comment: To make more explicit what others said: if you used a shorter length (e.g. 3 instead of 4) and a smaller alphabet (e.g. just `["a", "b", "c"]`), then your example will me much shorter, simpler, and self-contained, instead of an illegible 34 page PDF

Comment: Links has been removed you can generate files using code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question is "Why is `'lida'` not found in the file data while `'adil'` is?" the answer is: Because you used the wrong `itertools` function for your task (and/or misunderstood what it does).

`combinations` produces all *unique* subsequences, in order by position in the input iterable. Since your input iterable is in sorted order, your output's elements will always be in sorted order too; `'abcd'` will exist, but `'abdc'` won't, because `d` comes after `c` in the input (no ordering of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` *except* `'abcd'` will exist). If you want to include all the various permutations (so `'adil'` and `'lida'` both appear in the output), you'd want `itertools.permutations`, not `itertools.combinations`. Similarly, if you need a letter to be able to repeat (so `'aaaa'` is a possible output), you'd want `combinations_with_replacement` if only unique outputs desired as per `combinations`, or `product` (with a `repeat` argument passed by keyword) if you want all orderings as per `permutations`.

Be warned though, the number of outputs gets *much* larger for `permutations`; I'd strongly recommend not trying to store them all in memory. Just loop over the `permutations` object and `write` them one by one, e.g.:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as e:
   perms = map(''.join, permutations(iterable, size))   # map(''.join, ...) is an efficient way to change an iterable of tuples of str to single strs
   file.write(f'[{next(perms)!r}')  # Write open bracket and pull initial value
   # Iterate over remaining values
   for perm in perms:
       file.write(f',{perm!r}')  # Write comma and new value
   file.write(']')  # Write close bracket
```

which still produces a legal `list` literal in the file, and avoids adding any of those spaces you're trying to avoid in the first place, all without blowing your RAM trying to hold all the permutations at once.

Comment: Thank You I will try and figure it out see you again have a great time!